# Creating a many to many relation between 2 table using a 3rd table that will support on delete cascade

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following User entity:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual string UsernameLowercase { get { return Username.ToLowerInvariant(); } }

    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        var otherUser = obj as User;
        return (0 == string.CompareOrdinal(UsernameLowercase, otherUser.UsernameLowercase));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return UsernameLowercase.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and the following Role entity:

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual string RoleNameLowercase { get { return RoleName.ToLowerInvariant(); } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        var otherRole = obj as Role;
        return (0 == string.CompareOrdinal(RoleNameLowercase, otherRole.RoleNameLowercase));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return RoleNameLowercase.GetHashCode();
    } 
}
```

since a user can be assigned many roles I created a third entity called UserInRole a follows:

```
public class UserInRole
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        var other = obj as UserInRole;
        return (Role == other.Role && User == other.User);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return User.GetHashCode() ^ Role.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I would like to map between the UsersInRoles table and the User and Role tables using fluent nhibernate so that when I delete a user all the user's role defined in the UsersInRoles table are delete too automatically. 
Here is my current mapping class for the UserInRole entity:

```
public class UserInRoleMapping : ClassMap<UserInRole>
{
    public UserInRoleMapping()
    {
        Table("UsersInRoles");

        CompositeId().
            KeyReference(x => x.User,k => k.Not.Lazy(), "UserId").
            KeyReference(x => x.Role, k => k.Not.Lazy(), "RoleId");

    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: so far so good, what is that caused the problem for you?

Comment: @silent_warrior when I try to delete a user I get an error that I cannot delete since it has a child entity (the role assigned to the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching sometime I find [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/4g7HZozm_gM) discussion. I change my User entity to the following (Notice the new protected Roles property):

```
public class User
{
    private IList<UserInRole> _roles = new List<UserInRole>(); 

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual string UsernameLowercase { get { return Username.ToLowerInvariant(); } }

    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        var otherUser = obj as User;
        return (0 == string.CompareOrdinal(UsernameLowercase, otherUser.UsernameLowercase));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return UsernameLowercase.GetHashCode();
    }

    protected virtual IList<UserInRole> Roles
    {
        get { return _roles; }
        set
        {
            value.ThrowIfNull("value");
            _roles = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

The user mapping was changed to contain a HasMany definition as follows:

```
public abstract class UserMapping: ClassMap<User>
{
    protected UserMapping()
    {
        Table("Users");

        Map(x => x.Username).Column("Username").Length(20).Not.Nullable().Unique();
        Map(x => x.Password).Column("Password").Length(20).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Email).Column("Email").Length(50).Not.Nullable();

        //This line was missing
        HasMany<UserInRole>(Reveal.Member<User>("Roles")).
            Table("UsersInRoles").
            KeyColumn("UserId").
            Inverse().
            Cascade.Delete();
    }
}
```

Now when I delete a user the Roles are deleted as well without an error. When I look on the nhibernate logs I see 2 delete statement for a single Delete(user) call as follows:

```
13:18:39.950 [7] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - DELETE FROM UsersInRoles WHERE UserId = :p0 AND RoleId = :p1;:p0 = 7 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p1 = 3 [Type: Int32 (0)]
13:18:39.983 [7] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - DELETE FROM Users WHERE Id = :p0;:p0 = 7 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Hope this helps somebody. Your remarks are welcomed.